# RXJS : moving from of() to scheduled()

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I was using the of() operator to create observables with simple values, e.g. of(navigator.onLine) but I had to update RxJS version and I get this linter warning of is deprecated, use scheduled instead.

It's clearly not the exact same function and I should not be setting a scheduler.

How would you treat this ?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This <strike>is</strike> was an rxjs bug, which is <strike>still open</strike> closed. Check [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4723) for more information

You can monitor this issue and for the meantime use:

```
// tslint:disable-next-line:deprecation
of(navigator.onLine);
```

Comment: Oh! Alright, thanks... Should have read that a little further, the deprecation is only regarding of with a scheduler... So I guess it's the same with StartWith...

Comment: @kfa if you scroll down in that issue, you can see that `startWith` actually has a different problem, which you can solve with a typecast